# Can I break a try - catch in JS without throwing exception?

Tags: javascript, operators, try-catch

I'd like to silently break a `try` - `catch` in the `try` block if a condition applies. ( Without throwing an unneccessary exception )

```
foo = function(){

    var bar = Math.random() > .5;

    try{

          if( bar ) // Break this try, even though there is no exception here.

          //  This code should not execute if !!bar 

          alert( bar );

    }
    catch( e ){}

    // Code that executes if !!bar

    alert( true );

}

foo();
```

However, `return` is not an option, since the function is supposed to continue executing afterwards.

**UPDATE**

I'd like to still keep up the opportunity to use the `finally` block.

Comment: What about if( !bar ) ? (If around the rest of the code in the try block)

Comment: In case of `!bar`, the code should continue executing with line `alert( bar );`

Comment: @StevenPalinkas: blablabla meant smth like this `if (!bar){alert(bar);}`

Comment: @Andrey: That is what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: In this overly simplified case it's fine, but my question is noot about usage of if statements in try-catches.

Comment: You should only use *try..catch* as a last resort and only put in it the code that must be there. So if you have a condition that should exit the *try*, then put it beforehand so execution doesn't enter the block if it doesn't have to. In the above: `if (!bar) { try{...} catch(e){...} }`. So instead of *if bar is true, exit* it's *if bar is true, don't enter*.

Comment: I have to know, why would anyone need this? If feel like were have a case of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can label a block and break from it using the **break *label*** syntax

as per your edit, **finally** is still executed

```
foo = function(){
    var bar = Math.random() > .5;
    omgalabel: try {
        if( bar ) break omgalabel;
        console.log( bar );
        // code 
    }
    catch( e ){
        //  This code should not execute if !!bar 
    }
    finally {
        // Code that executes no matter what
        console.log( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: The much simpler and cleaner solution is to not enter the *try..catch* at all if *bar* is truthy. Labels are considered the equivalent of GOTO and are extremely rarely used.

Comment: Wow, you can break from a non-loop using a label?

Comment: @RobG preaching to the converted, but as the question is obviously dumbed down, who are we to judge. You want someone to rewrite 2000 lines of code just because you say try/catch is bad mmmkay. Sometimes as programmers we get to deal with other peoples code, and sometimes a rewrite is not the #1 priority. So, while I agree with your sentiment, and that the comment is a valid one on the question, there's no need to harp on about it in an answer, is there?

Comment: @Kos I learned that about 10 minutes ago - I would never see the need for it myself, but I too avoid try/catch as much as I can

Comment: Thanks for teaching me this. I don't care what people think of us, GOTO marriage is now legal in Javascript, hurray :D

Comment: it's NOT a goto, not even close ... it breaks OUT of a labelled block (the label is ABOVE the break statement, it does not allow you to jump to arbitrary labelled block - nested labelled blocks can be fun too - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break - it's closer to a return in an inner function ... sort of

Comment: It might be useful if the OP can show a case where the break logic can't be applied prior to entering the try block.

Comment: @RobG you want me to prove the validity of the question to justify my answer?

Comment: @RobG I said you're preaching to the converted, I said I rarely even use try/catch (except when dealing with stupid libraries - looking at you telerik) - but I've dealt with other peoples code, and it's horrendous (I'm sure more talented coders - both of them - think that about my code), and sometimes if you need to fix a problem fast, you have to dive into the shallow end of the pool, and worry about the rewrite when there's time

Comment: as a side note, Douglas Crawford talks about labelled blocks and break _label_ in "Javascript The Good Parts" ... so now I'm in two minds if it's good or not :p

Comment: @JaromandaX—it might be a good solution, it's just that the OP hasn't provided a good reason to use it vs doing the test before entering the block in the first place. There is also *with* and *eval*, but they are only recommended in rare cases where there's a clear reason (well, I've never seen a good reason to use *with*).  I just don't see one here. Not saying it doesn't exist, I'd just like to be convinced.

Comment: @RobG did _with_ even survive the trip to ES2015? and we all know _eval_ is _evil_ and _try_ / _catch_ is the tool of the devil, but our coding predecessors, god bless their little intellect were naive

Comment: [*ECMAScript ed 6 §13.11 The with Statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-with-statement).

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = function(){

    var bar = Math.random() > .5;
    if( ! bar ) {
        try{
            //  This code should not execute if !!bar 
            alert( bar );
        }
        catch( e ){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    // Code that executes no matter what
    alert( true );
}

foo();
```

Why don't you check the boolean before you enter the `try…catch`?

Comment: as the OP said in his question - this is a simplified example

Comment: @JaromandaX, even if the example is simplified, the question still remains. If this isn't possible, I think it might be the time to refactor :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var error;
var bar = Math.random() > .5;
try{
   if(bar){throw new Error('#!@$');} // Break this try, even though there is no exception here.
   //  This code should not execute if !!bar 
   alert( bar );
   }
catch(e){
   if(e.stack.indexOf('#!@$')==-1){error=e;}
   }
finally{
   if(error){
       //an actual error happened
       }
   else{
       // Code that executes if !!bar
       alert( true );
       }
   }
```

you can throw a error inside try catch and detect the string of the error stack to see if it was an expected throw or an actual error you didn't expect